# cross compile fontconfig for imx25 failure

Tags: arm, cross-compiling, fontconfig

**Cross compiler**:
Sourcery_G++_Lite/bin/arm-none-linux-gnueabi

Autoconfig failed on below checking of "grab the raw symbol name" with arm-none-linux-gnueabi-nm.

```
checking command to parse /opt/CodeSourcery/Sourcery_G++_Lite/bin/arm-none-linux-gnueabi-nm -B output from arm-none-linux-gnueabi-gcc object... **failed**
```

Eventually, this caused all checking for symbols failed.

```
checking for struct dirent.d_type... yes
checking The type of len parameter of gperf hash/lookup function... size_t
checking for FREETYPE... yes
checking for FT_Get_BDF_Property... no
checking for FT_Get_PS_Font_Info... no
checking for FT_Has_PS_Glyph_Names... no
checking for FT_Get_X11_Font_Format... no
checking for FT_Done_MM_Var... no
checking for EXPAT... yes
checking expat.h usability... yes
checking expat.h presence... yes
checking for expat.h... yes
checking for XML_SetDoctypeDeclHandler... no
configure: error: 
*** expat is required. or try to use --enable-libxml2
FAILED
```

libexpat has been cross-compiled and is avaialbe under root/usr/lib, autoconfig cannot detect it properly.

I believe the cross compiler toolchain works well, as it builds all other modules like Freetype, jpeg or png library. fontconfig is the only module that failed so far.

Any clue what can be the possible cause?

Comment: There is a 'configure.log', Go to the end, and it dumps many variables.  You need to scroll up (several pages) and look for the command that failed.  By looking at this, you can tell why it failed.

Comment: thanks for the information. the configuration was messed up due to cache.